# How to see active connections and "current activity" in PostgreSQL 8.4

Tags: postgresql

I'm investigating an issue with DB connections being left open indefinitely, causing problems on the DB server. How do I see currently open connections to a PostgreSQL server, particularly those using a specific database? Ideally I'd like to see what command is executing there as well. Basically, I'm looking for something equivalent to the "Current Activity" view in MSSQL.

Comment: from PostgreSQL 9.0 on you will even see the name of the application causing the problem. maybe this is helpful for future checks.

Answer (score 195):

OK, got it from someone else. This query should do the trick:

```
select *
from pg_stat_activity
where datname = 'mydatabasename';
```

Answer (score 34):

See also [pg-top](https://github.com/markwkm/pg_top), which acts like top except it shows postgres activity.

- Install pg-top (in Debian, the package is called "ptop").
- Become the postgres user (e.g. `sudo su postgres`)
- Run `pg_top`

Comment: So hard to find a windows executable. You (almost) never have the full GCC suite or Mingw on a Windows server (not my choice, don't blame me).

Comment: @oligofren Running Postgresql on Windows is a bit of an adventure, if for no other reason than that so many of the utilities and tools are written for Linux.

Comment: On buster, the debian package is called [pgtop](https://packages.debian.org/buster/pgtop)

Comment: The link is dead.

Answer (score 19):

[Reference taken from this article.](http://www.dbrnd.com/2015/09/script-to-find-active-sessions-or-connections-in-postgresql/)

```
SELECT 
    pid
    ,datname
    ,usename
    ,application_name
    ,client_hostname
    ,client_port
    ,backend_start
    ,query_start
    ,query  
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE state <> 'idle'
AND pid<>pg_backend_pid();
```

Comment: `query` and `pid` were named `current_query` and `procpid`, and `state` is not available in `pg_stat_activity` prior to PostgreSQL 9.2.

Answer (score 4):

Two ways to monitor in *Ubuntu 18.04*, just for reference

One using `pg_top`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ptop
$ pg_top # similar to top as others mentioned
```

Two using `pgAdmin4`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install pgadmin4 pgadmin4-apache2
# type in password and use default url
$ pgadmin4
```

In the dashboard, check the total/active as

[image]

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL ASH Viewer (PASH Viewer) provides graphical view of active session history data.
https://github.com/dbacvetkov/PASH-Viewer
It's free and open source.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZMFf.png)

Answer (score 1):

DBeaver is also showing the active/idle/total server sessions very nicely.